# Query returning Unexpected values

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * 
        FROM workshop_planning_history
        WHERE STATUS =1
        OR STATUS =2
        AND start_date =2015 -11 -29
        OR end_date <=2016 -01 -10
        OR end_date >=2016 -01 -10
```

I am running the above query and i am expecting values from Workshop_planning_history whose status is either 1 or 2 but i am getting results which have a status of 3 along with the rows having status 1 & 2.
What's wrong with my query please Help ...

Comment: What's 2016 minus 1 minus 10? See the manual regarding working with dates.

Comment: @Strawberry   haha , the questioner is a funny guy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add some parenthesis to the predicate, because the precedence of operators is `NOT AND OR`, so your query is interpreted as:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM workshop_planning_history
    WHERE STATUS = 1
          OR (STATUS = 2 AND start_date = '2015-11-29')
          OR end_date <= '2016-01-10'
          OR end_date >= '2016-01-10'
```

Change to:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM workshop_planning_history
    WHERE (STATUS = 1 OR STATUS = 2)
          AND (start_date = '2015-11-29'
               OR end_date <= '2016-01-10'
               OR end_date >= '2016-01-10')
```

Or something that is proper according to your logic.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do it would be using the `in` clause for `status`.

**Documentation**: [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html)

```
SELECT * 
    FROM workshop_planning_history
    WHERE STATUS in (1,2)
    AND start_date =2015 -11 -29
```

Also why use end_date if you use both `<=` & `>=` operators?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add  parentesis in between AND condition of status and date comparison also its good idea to use date modifier when comparing dates

```
 SELECT * 
        FROM workshop_planning_history
        WHERE (STATUS =1
        OR STATUS =2)
        AND (date(start_date) = date '2015 -11 -29'
        OR date(end_date) <=date '2016 -01 -10'
        OR date(end_date) >=date '2016 -01 -10')
```